# As a DM, what are important changes to the play caused by Detect Magic no longer being a cantrip in 5e?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic, cantrips, rituals

In D&D 3.5 and Pathfinder 1, Detect Magic was a cantrip. That meant it was possible to cast it a lot / infinite number of times per day, and get useful information in 1 to 3 rounds.

In 5e, it is a 1st level spell, but a ritual. It means that it still can be used quickly, or can be used indefinite number of times per day, but not both.

Given that worlds I DM are usually magic rich, what changes to the gameplay should I expect? How can I utilize this change in Detect Magic for the benefit of the story?

I'm not looking for an essay, just for **main points** that came with **your experience in DMing** 5e adventures with significant magic to be detected, or to stay hidden.

---

For future reference, in 3.5 Detect Magic uses were not always infinite, but they were much more accessible for three reasons:

1. they didn't compete for spell slots with Magic Missile and other non-cantrip spells, and there were more cantrip slots to begin with.
2. if needed, they still could use 1st level spell slots and
3. Magic Sensitive Reserve Feat (Complete Mage, p. 44) allowed you to effectively have it always on even without casting it at all.

Comment: I assume that this change was made for a reason, but designer intent is off topic, and I'm more interested in how it actually worked out than in the intent anyway.

Comment: How does "*if needed, they still could use 1st level spell slots*" make a cantrip more accessible, let alone in comparison to a system where it is a 1st level spell?

Comment: @TylerH this part, *taken out of context*, does not.

Comment: I'm including the full context you provided; just trying to get clarification as it doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @TylerH full context = points 1 and 3, and bonus spells per day from high ability scores.

Comment: I don't see how points 1 and 3 are relevant to the casting of a cantrip as a level 1 spell instead. If anything I would say point 2 *contradicts* point 1.

Answer (score 32):

## It makes time pressure more important

Unless the party has a Warlock who can cast Detect Magic at will, the party will have to make a choice. Do we use a ritual and take 10 minutes, or do we use a spell slot to know the answer right away?

I've had players who are absolutely paranoid and will try to keep Detect Magic active at all times, just in case some creature is an illusion, or they miss some sort of other magical phenomenon.

Because it takes 10 minutes (and 6 seconds) to cast the spell as a ritual, and the duration is 10 minutes, you can't keep it up permanently, so my party would walk around for ten minutes, then pause for 10 minutes to recast the spell.

Eventually they realized it was taking them twice as long to get to places and there was a risk/reward system at play when it comes to always wanting to be able to Detect Magic, and after a village was burned to the ground because they arrived an hour too late to stop it (because their 3 hour trip back from the dungeon became a 6 hour trip), they stopped trying to keep it active at all times.

If it is a cantrip, there's no real reason not to have it on if you're not concentrating on anything else.

*If that's a good or a bad thing depends entirely on your own personal opinion.*

Comment: +1. And I didn't ask about good or bad anyway :) It's a change, and I want to be able to make the most out of it, and not miss some important implications of such change. Remembering that it gets more important with increasing time pressure is a good point.

Comment: Your players are only paranoid because you are out to get them. :P

Comment: Now you sound just like one of my players @Slagmoth ;)

Comment: For the sake of completeness. In 3.5 cantrips were not unlimited, thus Detect Magic was only slightly more accesible than in 5e and it was definetly not possible to have it active at all times. +1 anyway.

Comment: @Ols in 3.5 they were much more accessible in three ways: 1) they didn't compete for spell slots with Magic Missile, 2) if needed, they still *could* use 1st level spell slots and 3) Magic Sensitive Reserve Feat ( Complete Mage, p. 44) allowed you to effectively have it always on even without casting it at all.

Comment: @Mołot Well, that is true, but having Detect Magic on indefifitly still required valuable resources like higher level slots or feats, not just time.

Comment: @Ols One divination prepared, and you still could cast it, so not a big cost if you were using divinations anyway. Worth for some, worthless for others, but even 1st level wizard without any special options could cast it 4 times, compared to 2 in 5e.

Comment: @Mołot  I admit that when I wrote "slightly" and "definetly not possible" in my first comment, I was wrong. But I still think that an average spellcaster wouldn't keep Detect Magic on all the time in 3.5 while in Pathfinder 1e it is much more likely.

Comment: @Ols I never said it was kept all the time, I said it was much more available, and that I DMed worlds with quite a lot of magic going on, so it was used. That said, evaluating this change in the light of published worlds or adventures would be an interesting answer I'd gladly upvote, even if it would show that it usually detect magic (and changes in how it works) wasn't that important as it was in my games.

Comment: @Mołot Yes, absolutely, you were not talking about keeping it all the time, but I was commenting on the answer, not the question. Anyway, we are discussing a sidetopic, the difference between 3.5 and PF while the question is about 5e. I totaly agree that in 5e Detect Magic is much less available than in the other two. I was just nitpicking.

Answer (score 9):

### What we found: without a wizard, our cleric keeps Detect Magic prepared

This choice was made as we had gone back and forth between relying on the Wizard to use it as a ritual from his book, or be able to cast it.  Since both the wizard and my cleric can prepare the spell, and cast it as a ritual, we defaulted to "Cleric keeps Detect Magic Prepared."

This frees the wizard up to prepare his optimallly effective spell choices.  My cleric's "go to spells" are not huge in number and we have found that the domain "free" prepared spells are the ones she uses most frequently.  Having detect magic available seems necessary.  It is usually used as a ritual, but now and again, I burn the spell slot and cast it *in situ* (doors blocking our flight was one such use early in our career).  Knowing there was something magical on the doors helped us figure out how to open them.

In two other games that are now dormant, the cleric in the group always kept it prepared as a ritual.  In one, my warlock didn't want to use an invocation (Eldritch Sight) for that.  In the other our sorcerer was considered to be a bad choice to use spell slots for detect magic: the cleric kept it prepared.

In a higher level one shot (Tier 3) my druid kept it prepared and only ever used it as a ritual (twice) during that adventure. In both cases it was while we were investigating and the group was trying to find out what, in the room, was magical.

#### The spell is most often cast as a ritual in our campaigns

In other campaigns, where people want to use it a lot (as you described in your OP) I can see how the "only use it as a ritual" approach can create time problems.  Which is good.  But in our case, it mostly ends up being a case of "is this stuff that we found (now that the battle is over) magical in nature?"  There is often a pause anyway, so the cleric doing a ritual detect magic *fits the pacing of our game*.

#### *Pacing* as a concern (DM side as much as player side)

I was only in one game where the pacing (it was almost a pure dungeon crawl) worked against the above approach, but in that game I wasn't playing a cleric.